# How Disable ARcore Sceneform Lighting?

Tags: java, android, arcore, sceneform

Base on ARcore Develop Guide ([Lighting Estimation developer guide for Android](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/light-estimation/developer-guide-java)), I am trying disable the light in the Scenceform. But nothing happen.

```
 arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener(
            (HitResult hitResult, Plane plane, MotionEvent motionEvent) -> {
                if (objectRenderable == null) return;
                // Create the Anchor.
                Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();
                AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
                anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
                anchorNode.setSmoothed(true);
                objectRenderable.setShadowReceiver(false);
                objectRenderable.setShadowCaster(false);
                updateLight();
                TransformableNode transformableNode = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
                transformableNode.getScaleController().setMaxScale(15.0f);
                transformableNode.getScaleController().setMinScale(1.0f);
                transformableNode.setParent(anchorNode);
                transformableNode.setRenderable(objectRenderable);
                transformableNode.select();
            });

private void updateLight() {
    Session session = new Session(this);
    // Configure the session with the Lighting Estimation API turned off.
    Config config = session.getConfig();
    config.setLightEstimationMode(Config.LightEstimationMode.DISABLED);
    session.configure(config);
}
```

The problem looks like I can not get the context session, science I got error " E/ARCore-AuthenticationManager: Exception during AuthenticationManager construction: com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability"

Comment: Have you got any solution for the above exception?

Comment: No yet, this problem base on get ARcore AR session, but there is some bug about to get ar session. I already post bug report to google github, still not get any response. https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/935

Answer (score 0):

You should get your current session and change it instead, try this:

```
class AppArFragment : ArFragment() {
    fun disableLight() {
        arSceneView.session?.apply {
            val changedConfig = config
            changedConfig.lightEstimationMode = Config.LightEstimationMode.DISABLED
            configure(changedConfig)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: humm.. I do not think these code content is different with my code. I found the problem is when I get session from context. I got error " E/ARCore-AuthenticationManager: Exception during AuthenticationManager construction: com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability"

Comment: Btw, are you trying to disable light or Light estimation api?

Comment: Do you base your project on any of the samples?

Comment: Yes I would like disable light estimation, and my project not base on any sample project.